# Active record two level association and group by count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Consider the following association

**Companies**

```
has_many: departments
```

**Departments**

```
belongs_to: company
has_many: employees
```

**Employees**

```
belongs_to: department
```

Consider the following sample data

**Companies**

```
+------------+--------------+
| company_id | company_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Company A    |
|          2 | Company B    |
+------------+--------------+
```

**Departments**

```
+---------------+------------+-----------------+
| department_id | company_id | department_name |
+---------------+------------+-----------------+
|             1 |          1 | Administration  |
|             2 |          1 | Development     |
|             3 |          1 | Designing       |
+---------------+------------+-----------------+
```

**Employees**

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| employee_id | department_id | employee_name | employee_grade |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
|           1 |             1 | EmpA          | grade1         |
|           2 |             1 | EmpB          | grade1         |
|           3 |             2 | EmpC          | grade1         |
|           4 |             2 | EmpD          | grade2         |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Is there a one liner in RoR to find the count of employees of a company, belongs to each grade? ie if company_id is equal to 1 then the output is as follows

```
+--------+-------+
| grade  | count |
+--------+-------+
| grade1 |     3 |
| grade2 |     1 |
+--------+-------+
```

A way I tried is to get departments for the company and then loop through it, fetch the grade grouped employee count for each department and add the counts. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I got a way.

Add another association in company using `through` to employees. So Company will become as follows

```
has_many :departments
has_many :employees, :through => :departments
```

And then to find the count do as following.

```
Company.find([company_id]).employees.group('employee_grade').count
```

Any other approach will be appreciated.